# How to detect scrolling speed of a video/How to detect differences in images

Tags: opencv, graphics, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have some screen recording videos from which I want to extract some information. My thinking is to use cv2.VideoCapture() to get screenshots and then use OCR to get information. But there is a limit to how many times I can call OCR service(a business service). So I want to only use the critical screenshots that don't have much information overlap. For example, I got 300 screenshots from cv2 but I can already get all the information needed from 20 of them since the scrolling speed is slow and most of the screenshots are overlapped.

See a real example: I want to get all the app names in a screen recording video of AppStore. 
[image]

The question is:

How can I find out the scrolling speed of the video so that I can adjust how often I capture a screenshot. Or to put it in another way: how can I find out how much the consecutive screenshots change, which actually implies the speed of scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use optical flow processing to detect scrolling, there will be only one dimension Y in flow detected so it will be easy to get the average scrolling by calculating the average of flows vector norm.

you can find here a python example to adapt easily in your case:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html